# error when try to run npm build on react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

i'm trying to deploy my app via VPS (Ubuntu and Nginx) but this error keeps showing up, (on vs code it works fine) any idea how could i procede? thanks!

```
> mystery@0.1.0 build /home/react-projects/portfolio
> react-scripts build

/home/react-projects/portfolio/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js:110
  _ending;
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/react-projects/portfolio/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/getESLint.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mystery@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mystery@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-23T18_10_04_282Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you using create-react-app? Which version of React are you using?

Comment: hi @Camilo, yes i am, react 18.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Updating node to higher version worked for me, i was using v10.22.1: **nvm use --lts**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33097444)

Answer (score 0):

**one way you can  :**

1. go to your **package.json**
2. replace `"react-scripts": "..."` to `"react-scripts": "1.1.4"`,
3. then run **npm install**, after that **npm build**

**if it didn't work try :**

1. create a file  `.env`  at the root of the folder react folder
2. type `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` inside of `.env` file

this command will help you in resolving this npm error.

then try to run `npm build`  and check it should work .

**notice** :  this command will permanently disable this preflight check

Answer (score -1):

i solved it installing the correct versions through NVM on my web server

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-and-update-npm-to-the-latest-version/