# Trying to install React, facing massive blocker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jestjs, react-scripts

/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js:110
_ending;
^

There's gotta be some guide out there on the step to take to fix this, or some other specific folder to delete. I just don't know what to do at this point.
[image: just why]

I have literally deleted, reinstalled npm, node, everything under the sun but this one error just keeps coming back.

Comment: What's the Node version?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74848909/react-js-npm-run-start-return-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73464400/error-when-try-to-run-npm-build-on-react-project

Comment: Please post code, config, and errors as formatted text rather than images.

Comment: second link fixed it, thanks